# Angular - Cannot resolve all parameters for HttpService: ([object Object], ?, ?)

Tags: angular, service, constructor

I created an HttpService to handle http requests to the backend, and this service inherits its methods to other services that provide the endpoint for the backend through the constructor.

So far when testing in my local machine, I had not encountered any issue so far. This error only appears when building for prod.

Here is the HttpService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { backendURL } from './../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  protected url:   string;
  protected token: string;

  constructor(
    protected http:         Http,
    protected endpoint:     String,
    private parentEndpoint: String
  ) {
    this.url = backendURL;
    this.token = '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And an example of how it's being inherited to other service:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpService } from './../http/http.service';

@Injectable()
export class CourseService extends HttpService {
  constructor(http: Http) { super(http, '/endpoint', '/parentEndpoint/'); }
}
```

I'm not sure what am I missing here? I saw other posts where this error is caused by circular dependency, but I don't think that's the case here unless I'm missing out the obvious.

Comment: Be sure your production environment file contains a `backendURL` property.

Comment: You seem to have provided HttpService, although it can't possibly be constructed by Angular. It shouldn't be decorated with Injectable, AFAIK, since it's not a service, but only a base class for services. That said, you're still using the deprecated Http service (which will probably disappear for Angular 6, coming out in a few weeks), and are still using old, non-pipeable operators, which will also disappear soon. And what you have in the base class should probably be in a http interceptor.

Comment: can you put the hole stacktrace error?

Comment: The backendURL is available in the prod environment file. I took away the Injectable decorator and still the same error. The stacktrace error pretty much only shows that one line of error. I notice though that it actually builds everything but shows the error anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I took away the Injectable decorator to the class, but I also had to remove the HttpService from the providers array at AppModule.

That made the trick.